# JavaScript currying: return a function defined outside the current function

Tags: javascript, closures, currying

I'm studying currying functions in JS and I got stuck with this problem.

My goal is to order an array of objects by a non-arbitrary property.

```
let people = [
    { name: 'Bob', age: 27 },
    { name: 'Al',  age: 47 }
];

var compare = function(a, b) {
    if (a[property] < b[property]) return -1;
    if (a[property] > b[property]) return 1;
    return 0;
};

function sortBy(property) {
    /* // this works
    return function compare(a, b) {
        if (a[property] < b[property]) return -1;
        if (a[property] > b[property]) return 1;
        return 0;
    };
    */

    // this doesn't work
    return compare;
}

people.sort(sortBy('name'));
console.log(people);
```

With this code I get this error:

```
if (a[property] < b[property]) return -1;
          ^
ReferenceError: property is not defined
```

Why if I define the `compare` function inside the `sortBy` function I don't get any error, and instead if I define the `compare` function outside I get an error?

The `compare` function should not be enclosed in a closure?

Comment: JavaScript has lexical scoping, not dynamic one. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science))

Comment: "The compare function should not be enclosed in a closure?" Why?

Comment: Because there’s no “property” when... there’s no “property”. I’m not sure what you’re expecting or asking—if you want “property” available it has to exist.

Comment: In this line ` if (a[property] < b[property]) return -1;` , what would `property` even refer to? You're not passing it into the function, nor is it a global variable, or locally accessible. However it IS locally accessible when you define the function inside `sortBy`

Answer (score 0):

The best I can find is using [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), but it's not perfect as it forces you to add `this` in `compare` which means you can't use it without having it binded

This happens because returning a function doesn't bind the current scope to it unless it was created in the current scope [this question may help understand better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

```js
let people = [
    { name: 'Bob', age: 27 },
    { name: 'Al',  age: 47 }
];

var compare = function(a, b) {
    if (a[this.property] < b[this.property]) return -1;
    if (a[this.property] > b[this.property]) return 1;
    return 0;
};

function sortBy(property) {
    return compare.bind({property});
}

people.sort(sortBy('name'));
console.log(people);
```